# jQuery Drop Down menu - on click visible

Tags: jquery, html

I need a drop down menu which should do two things.

1. When we hover, sub menu should be visible. When the mouse taken out, it should hide.
2. When user clicks on menu or its sub menu, then the sub menu should be visible. It should not hide when mouse taken out.

I tried this, but it is not working...

HTML

```
<ul id="navigation">
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#1">Home</a>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#2">Solutions</a>
        <ul class="sub_navigation">
            <li><a href="#2">Video</a></li>
            <li><a href="#3">Animation</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('body').ready(function() {
    $('.dropdown').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('.sub_navigation').slideToggle(); 
    });
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('body').ready(function() {
    $('.dropdown a').click(function() {
        $(this).find('.sub_navigation').show(); 
    });
});
 </script>
```

Please give some tips...

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rough way of doing this would be:
First of all you should hide your sub_navigation i.e

```
.sub_navigation{
    display:none;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('body').ready(function() {
    $('.dropdown').hover(function() {
        if(!$(this).hasClass("isClicked")){
        $(this).find('.sub_navigation').slideToggle();
        }
    });
    $('.dropdown').click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('isClicked');
    });
    $('.dropdown .sub_navigation').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().addClass("isClicked");
    });
});
```

​

See Working solution [here](http://jsfiddle.net/evM46/)